$2014$ numbers ($1$ or $-1$) are arranged in a circle. Which of {$-100,1606,2018,-8,-51$} could be the sum of all products of $4$ consecutive numbers?

$2014$ numbers are arranged in a circle, each $1$ or $-1$. We take the product of every $4$ consecutive numbers on the circle. We then take the sum of all $2014$ products. Then the sum can be ...
A. $\;-100\quad$ B. $\;1606\quad$ C. $\;2018\quad$ D. $\;-8\quad$ E. $\;-51$

my idea
Considering that it says "the amount can be", we will refer strictly to the answer options:
The variants are: $-100$, $1606$, $2018$, $-8$, $-51$.
A product of $4$ consecutive numbers can be $1$ or $-1$.
It asks us to find the sum of the $2014$ products, that is, the sum of the $2014$ $1$'s or $-1$'s, I repeat we don't know how many $1$'s and how many $-1$'s there are.
Someone told me to look only for $M_4+2$, where $M_4$ is a multiple of $4$ because $2014:4=503$ remains $2$, but I don't understand why the solution should only take this form.
Hope one of you can help me! Thanks!

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Label the numbers $a_1$ through $a_{2014}$. When $2014$ numbers are put around a circle, there are exactly $2014$ distinct $4$-tuples (with regard to ordering) of consecutive numbers around the circle. Now since $a_n \in \{-1,1\}$ when $a_n=1$ or $a_n=-1$ identically, sum of products of all elements of each of said $4$-tuples (denoted now by $S$) is $2014$.
Claim: $S$ is invariant $\bmod 4$.
Suppose we change some $a_n$ from its initial state $1$ to $-1$ or vice versa, changing $S\to S’$. Note that $a_n$ contributes to exactly $4$ terms in $S$ all of which are odd (since each term is just $\pm 1$). The sum of $4$ odd values is always even.
Then $\pmod 4 : S \equiv a_n(2k) + \cdots$ and $S’ \equiv -a_n(2k) + \cdots$
It follows that $S-S’ \equiv 2a_n(2k)$. It follows $S\equiv S’ \pmod 4$.
Now since one value that $S$ takes is $2014$, it must be the case that we must have always $S\equiv 2\pmod 4$. This leaves only the option $(B) \ 1606$ as a viable value that can be achieved for $S$.

Let's start with canceling options that are not possible:
C.2018 is surely not possible because there can be at most 2014 +1 products,
E. -51 is not possible, because there must be an even number of +1 and -1 products that cancel out and then 51-1 products, because the sum of the numbers of these products is 2014, there will odd number of +1 and -1 in total which then means that there cannot be a total even number of +1 and -1 products that cancel each other out. This is a contradiction.
We are now left with options A,B and D, et us analyze them one by one:
A:
For there to be a result of -100 there must be 100 -1 products and then there must be $(2014-100)/2=957$ of each -1 and +1 products that cancel each other out, that means that there are 1057 -1 products and 957 +1 products, each product can be expressed as such: (I'll sometimes write P for +1 and N for -1 so there isn't confusion and it's faster)
1 can be expressed as a product of  a) 4P, b)2P and 2N c) 4N,
-1 can be expressed as a product of a)3P 1N, b)3N 1P,
(PS:the numbers before P and N mean the how many numbers there are in the product, it's not a multiplication)
Notice that every number in the circle will appear in distinct products exactly 4 times, that means that if we sum up the numbers of P and N, that means that the numbers of P and N are divisible by 4, and when  we sum them up and divide them by 4 we will get exactly 2014. For the products of -1, we will always add either 3 or 1 to the numbers of P or N, considering there is an odd number of -1 products in total we will in total add an odd number of odd numbers to the number of P or N, for the +1 products we will always be adding an even number to the number of P or N (it doesn't depend on the number of +1 products), considering we already have an odd number from the -1 products, adding an even number will give us an odd number of  P and N, we cannot divide these by 4, thus this option is not valid.
B:
For there to be a result of 1606 there must be 1606 +1 products and $(2014-1606)/2=204$ of each +1 and -1 products that cancel each other out, there are thus 1810 +1 products and 204 -1 products, we will use the same method from the previous paragraph: for the +1 products we will always add an even number to the numbers of P and N, for the -1 products we have an even number of products this means that we will add odd numbers to the number of P and N an even number of times which will result in adding an even number from the products of -1 to an even number from the products of +1 which will result in an even number of P and N, the question arises: Can we also make the numbers of P and N divisible by 4? yes, for example: for the products of -1 we can always add 3 to the number of P and 1 to N, and then 1 to P and 3 to N, for the products of +1 we can either: add 4 to the number of P and 0 to N, then add 0 to P and 4 to N, or we can always add 2 to P and 2 to N. We can sure make the numbers of P and N divisible by 4. This option is valid.
D:
For there t be a sum of -8 there must be 8 -1 and $(2014-8)/2=1003$ of each -1 and +1 products to cancel each other out. That means that there will be 1011 -1 products and 1003 +1 products, for the +1 products we will always add an even number to the numbers of P and N, this will result in an even number of numbers of P and N from the +1 products, for the -1 products we have an odd number of them so this will result in adding an odd number to the numbers of P and N, adding the odd number to the even number from the +1 products will give us an odd number of both P and N, these are not divisible by 4 so D is not valid.
The only valid option is B. I would like to generalize this to the rule where the sum $S$ must have the property $S\equiv 2\ (\textrm{mod}\ 4)$. S must be even, because there must in total be an even number of +1 and -1 products that cancel out to make the given sum, and adding the number of given +1 and -1 products for the sum must give 2014 thus S must be even. There must be an even number of +1 and -1 products, because in total we will always add  an even number to the numbers of P and N from the +1 products, we must also in total add an even number from the -1 products so that the numbers of P and N will be even and divisible by 4 ( we can always make the numbers of P and N divisible by 4 in this case, but i'll leave that up to you to figure out). We know that the numbers of +1 products and -1 products are equal and even, so adding these will give us a number divisible by 4, because S is the total of -1 or +1 products that are needed to construct it, and the number K of the remaining products that cancel each other out is as we have said divisible by 4, we know that the number of products (either +1 or -1) needed to create S is $|S|$, and this is true: $K+|S|=2014$ (where K is divisible by 4 <=> $K\equiv 0\ (\textrm{mod}\ 4))$, then because $2014 \equiv 2\ (\textrm{mod}\ 4)$ then $|S|\equiv2-K\ (\textrm{mod}\ 4) <=> |S|\equiv 2\ (\textrm{mod}\ 4)$ (if S is negative it is the same $-2\equiv2\ (\textrm{mod}\ 4)$), and surely the number 1606 has remainder 2 after dividing by 4.
The final answer to your question is option B.
